# Convert two strings to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to calculate the time between two dates. One of the dates is today and the other date is somewhere in the future.

The issue is the date in future is separated into two string, the first containing the date and the other containing the time for that date. When i put the two strings together to a single string and try to convert it to a NSDate i get **Nil**.

I assume there is something wrong with my **date** variable.

```
let eventDate: String? = "21 Aug Sun 2016"
let eventTime: String? = "9:00 PM"

let date : String? =  "\(eventDate!) \(eventTime!)"

    print(date!) // "21 Aug Sun 2016 9:00 PM"

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM eee yyyy HH:MM a"
    formatter.AMSymbol = "AM"
    formatter.PMSymbol = "PM"

    if let dateTimeForEvent = formatter.dateFromString(date!) {
        print(dateTimeForEvent)
    }else {
        print("Error")// prints error

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You have the wrong format for the time. It should be `h:mm a`. `HH` is for a two-digit, 24-hour hour. You have a 1 or 2 digit, 12-hour hour. And `MM` is for a 2-digit month. Use `mm` for a two-digit minute.
2. If your date and time strings will always be in English, you need to set the formatter's locale to an English locale. If you don't, your code will always return a `nil` date on any device using a language other than English.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary issue is that you're using `HH`, which is for 24-hour time, instead of `hh`, and `MM` (which is for month) instead of `mm`. Try this:

import Foundation

```
let eventDate = "21 Aug Sun 2016"
let eventTime = "9:00 PM"

let eventDateTime =  "\(eventDate) \(eventTime)"

print(eventDateTime) // "21 Aug Sun 2016 9:00 PM"

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM eee yyyy hh:mm a"

if let date = formatter.dateFromString(eventDateTime) {
    print(date) // 2016-08-21 21:00:00 +0000
}
else {
    print("Error")// prints error, no shit? why is this comment here?
}
```

Side notes:

- Why is a variable called `date`, if it's a `String?`?
- Why is `date` an optional, anyway? You assigned it a literal value.
- You don't have to set the `AMSymbol` and the `PMSymbol`. Those only pertain to printing dates, not parsing them.